# Iterate through 1D array and 2D array with step

Tags: c++, arrays

Iterating through 1D array (pseudo 2D) with step of 3:

```
arr = new int[height * width * 3];
for (int i = 0; i < height * width * 3; i+=3) {
  arr[i] = 1;   
}
```

I have tried this, but what I got is column of one third:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height * 3; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x+=3) {
        arr[x + width * y] = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your cells have a 'size' of 3 entries, you should use the `* 3` on the inner loop. Otherwise you miss 2 thirds of your cells on each row.
You also need to multiply `width` by 3 to get the correct row.

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width * 3; x+=3) {
        arr[x + width * 3 * y] = 1;
    }
}
```

In general you need the following structure for such situations:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width * cellWidth; x+= cellWidth) {
        arr[x + width * cellWidth * y] = 1;
    }
}
```

(Were `cellWidth` is 3 in your case)

To slightly simplify this, you could assume in the loops that your cells have a width of 1 (like a normal situation) and multiply by `cellWidth` when actually assigning the values:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        int index = (x + width * y) * cellWidth;
        arr[index + 0] = 1; // First 'cell entry'
        arr[index + 1] = 1; // Second
        ...
        arr[index + cellWidth - 1] = 1; // Last
    }
}
```

Another solution is to create larger 'items' using a `struct` for example:

```
typedef struct { int r, int g, int b } t_rgb;
t_rgb* arr = new t_rgb[height * width];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        arr[x + width * y].r = 1;
    }
}
```

and you are able to use it as a regular array (the compiler does all calculations for you). This also makes it more clear what is happening in your code.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Setting a channel in a RGB image?
I usually do it like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        arr[(x + width * y) * 3] = 1;
```

In general, to set RGB values, you can simply add an offset like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        size_t base = (x + width * y) * 3;
        arr[base + 0] = r;
        arr[base + 1] = g;
        arr[base + 2] = b;
    }
```